# React Native Image Border Radius too big

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

[image]

I do have a black box (the background) with a border radius of 10. When I do have a larger image (the brown part is a part of an image) it works fine and the image also does have a border radius of 10. But when I do have smaller images, like this one, I do have such a large radius even when I set it to 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

border-radius determines the rounding of edges on an element. If it is being inconsistent with regards to size try using a percentage for the value. Such as.

```
borderRadius: "10%"
```

Comment: Sadly I get an javascript error :(

Comment: can you share where you added the code? If you are adding it in js it would be something like
    object.style.borderRadius = '10%'

Comment: How I said I use React Native. It has their own css like style system

Comment: Ah okay put the percentage in quotations like 
borderRadius: "10%"

Comment: When I do this I get a java error :/